# What is the proper way to get the karma test coverage path into Travis CI?

Tags: code-coverage, glob, karma-runner, travis-ci, code-climate

I'm using [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io) to run unit tests and generate coverage reports. That all works fine but I want to publish the `lcov.info` file to Code Climate from [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org). I've [done it before](https://github.com/daniellmb/AQUA/blob/master/.travis.yml#L10) and it [works great](https://codeclimate.com/github/daniellmb/AQUA), but the url from that test runner was static.

The issue is that karma creates a subfolder for each instance it runs such as `test/coverage/PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)/lcov.info`. Is there a clean way to get that url to feed into travis? I don't want to have to remember to update a hardcoded value every time PhantomJS gets updated. Does anyone know if the `.travis.yml` file supports something like [glob patterns](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A glob pattern will work and I'm using it successfully with a karma/travis/codeclimate set up.

Using

```
codeclimate < test/coverage/**/lcov.info
```

should work assuming have the CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN variable set.

Also, options to change the subdirectory structure is being discussed on https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/pull/62.

Comment: Outstanding! I'll give that a try

Comment: Yep, I [tried it](https://github.com/daniellmb/once.js/blob/master/.travis.yml#L10) out and [worked perfectly](https://github.com/daniellmb/once.js#oncejs)