# Travis CI Can't Find Karma Generated lcov.info File

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, karma-runner, travis-ci, code-climate

I'm trying to get CodeClimate's code coverage to work on [my GitHub Repo](https://github.com/AquilaSagitta/daVinci). Travis CI doesn't find the lcov.info file that is generated by Karma after testing. I tried using a glob like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537778/what-is-the-proper-way-to-get-the-karma-test-coverage-path-into-travis-ci) answer but even `codeclimate-test-reporter < **/*lcov.info` doesn't work.

Karma generates the `lcov.info` file in `/coverage/PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0)/lcov.info`. I've set the token environment variable in Travis CI and locally.

Running this locally works:

```
codeclimate-test-reporter < "coverage/PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0)/lcov.info"
```

Running it in Travis CI via .travis.yml does not work. [Travis CI can't find the file.](http://puu.sh/jj3zQ/0201e8e7d6.png)

Karma.conf.js

```
coverageReporter: {
  type : 'lcovonly',
  dir : 'coverage/'
}
```

.travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.12"
  - "0.11"
  - "0.10"
  - "iojs"
after_script:
  - npm install codeclimate-test-reporter
  - codeclimate-test-reporter < **/*lcov.info
```

So whats the deal? Is karma not generating the file before Travis CI tries to access it? Is it getting generated in some other directory? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to install `codeclimate-test-reporter` globally instead of locally